# Unit Testing Object State

Tags: c#, unit-testing, object

I have some difficulties unit testing object states. Take the following scenario:

```
public class DemoClass
{
    private int state;

    public DemoClass(int state)
    {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int State
    {
        get { return this.state; }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        state++;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class DemoClassTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomething_NoParam_StateEqualsThree()
    {
        var demoClass = new DemoClass(2);
        demoClass.DoSomething();

        Assert.AreEqual(3, demoClass.State);
    }
}
```

The method in test takes no argument and returns no value, so I am not testing that, but its effects on the object. The result of that also depends on how the object was initialized.
 

So is this a correct unit test, and is the name of the unit test correct?

Comment: I'd prefer a more functional name of the unit test method. Not a name that elaborates about implementation details, like `NoParam`. For the rest, a test that executes a method, and then checks the subject under test seems fine. If the property `State` is made public just for the test, it is probably a code smell which could make you investigate if there is something not quite OK design-wise.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would name a unit test? The main problem I have with the name I've chosen is, that the value passed to the constructor is not taken into account.

Comment: Assuming you already have a test for the constructor that verifies that `State` is initialized correctly, having a test name like `DoSomethingIncrementsState` seems like it describes what you're actually testing.  If you really want the values, then you could use some kind of Given/When/Then naming something like `GivenStateTwo_DoSomething_ThenStateThree`, or you could look at parametrised tests.